# AJAX call producing additional records instead of updating

Tags: jquery, ajax, mustache

so I have sat my AJAX call inside of an `$("button").on("click")` jQuery method.

so when ever I click the `button` element the AJAX call gets activated and adds values to the mustache template.

```
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>

<div id="template-container">
    <template id="my-template">
        <p>my name is:{{0}} and i am {{1}} living in {{2}}</p>
    </template>
</div>

<script>
  $(function(){
    var templateContainer= $('#template-container');
    var myTemplate= $("#my-template").html();

    function addInfo(info){
      templateContainer.append(Mustache.render(myTemplate, info));
    };

    $( "button" ).on( "click", function() {

        // requesting data returns an array as such: [["name1", "34", "city1"],["name2", "23", "city2"]]
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: '/get_data',
          success: function(dataArray){
          console.log(dataArray)
            $.each(dataArray, function(i, info){
              addInfo(info);
            });
          },
          error: function(){
            alert("error loading infos");
          }
        });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Now what happens when I click the button `$("button")` is that the data are added to the template successfully as bellow:

```
my name is:name1 and i am 34 living in city1

my name is:name2 and i am 23 living in city2
```

the problem happens when i click the button `$("button")` again, it adds the same array below the previous one giving the following output:

```
my name is:name1 and i am 34 living in city1

my name is:name2 and i am 23 living in city2

my name is:name1 and i am 34 living in city1

my name is:name2 and i am 23 living in city2
```

how can I force the `$("button").on("click")` method to remove the previous outputs whenever the button is clicked so that replications don't occur??

**UPDATE**

I have tried deleting the infos before appending to the container `templateContainer` using `templateContainer.empty()` as user [Kevin B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400654/kevin-b) suggested.

```
function addInfo(info){
    templateContainer.empty();
    templateContainer.append(Mustache.render(myTemplate, info));
};
```

however, it is now only showing the last item of the array as such:

```
my name is:name2 and i am 23 living in city2
```

Comment: I mean... the only thing occurring after the ajax request is `addRecord`, but you haven't included that in your question... so....

Comment: sorry that was a typo, I minimized the code as much as I could @KevinB

Comment: Ok, so, you're using jQuery's append method, and you're not emptying the target container before you start appending, so, it's going to append everything you tell it to after all the things that are already there. You could instead empty it first each time, seems like that'd be a reasonable solution.

Comment: I tried using jQuery `.empty()`, `.detach()` and `.remove()` methods but did not work. to be honest with you, I am not sure where and on what container should i apply them. Could you please help me out @KevinB

Comment: well, the container you're appending to of course. `templateContainer`

Comment: where exactly should I put the `.remove()` method ?

Comment: the .remove method isn't useful for your needs.

Comment: yeah it did not work,  what method should I approach that is more suitable?

Comment: I can not empty the target container before appending as you suggested because the appending process is inside a loop! `$.each(dataArray, function(i, info){
              addInfo(info);
            });` in each `each()` loop the container gets emptied leaving me with the last item of the array @KevinB

Comment: Who said do it inside the loop? Ideally, it should occur *before* the loop.

Comment: it does not allow it saying that `templateContainer.empty is not a function`

Comment: Sounds like you somehow redefined templateContainer incorrectly.

Comment: what can i possibly do now?

Comment: Undo all of the changes you made to your code, bringing it back to where it was in your question. Now add the .empty call before the loop. If you still get .empty is not a function, you didn't undo enough.

Comment: you mean inside the `success` function before `each()`?.. I already did that it does not work saying templateContainer.empty it is not a function

Comment: Then your code doesn't match what is in your question.

Comment: well I am using a `selector` in `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )` method. is that it? I tried to make the code as simple as possible for readers to understand and this is the only difference that i can point out at the moment

Comment: That wouldn't cause `templateContainer` to all of a sudden not be a jquery collection.

Comment: do i have to make it a global variable?

Comment: No, as long as it is where it is in your question relative to the click handler, all within the `$(function(){`

Comment: it is! do you know any possible problem that may cause this?

Comment: okay i have noticed something, when i do a `console.log(templateContainer )` after the initilization of the variable it gives me a DOM element . but when i do a `console.log(templateContainer )` in the success function it gives the array!! that should not be happening am I wrong?

Comment: FOUND IT ><. turned out i was writing `success: function(templateContainer){` instead of `success: function(dataArray){` that what caused the `templateContainer` to be redefined. thank you so so much sir for helping me figuring this out. you make a good teacher you know ;) thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** add this line before the each:

```
templateContainer.children("p").remove();
```

or

```
  templateContainer.empty();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you for helping. it's giving the last item of the array just like the update :(

Comment: @jes there is a function used here in sctackoverflow i can give you an example it does the same thing that mustache does, i can give you a fiddle if you want =)

Comment: thanks stan, kevin b is saying that the emptying should occur before the loop, any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: addInfo is called in a loop, so each iteration you are removing the items.... This answer with `templateContainer.empty().append` will not work because of that.